# Writing an alternative interface to Facebook

Tags: facebook

Hypothetically, suppose I wanted to produce an alternative user interface to Facebook. How complete could it be and what would be the most important features that couldn't be implemented?

Comment: Hypothetically, one could assume that Facebook API:s would actually work reliably enough to replicate any larger set of FB's functionality through them... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would be able to reproduce about 5% if not less.

- You would stuck right away at login form as it cannot be reproduced outside of facebook :) You can't login through API without forwarding a user to facebook web page or popup.
- You can't register a new user either.
- Search abilities are very limited. You can't make any detailed searches through Graph API. Using FQL wouldn't help much either as 90% table fields and not indexed and not available for searching.
- Most data queries are limited to latest 5,000 entries, anything older is invisible to API.
- What is public on facebook site not always visible to API without extended permissions
- Like button cannot be reproduced
- There is no API for creating new applications

and many more...

Comment: With the exception of the Like button. these all seem like smallish limitations, compared to the activities of a typical user.